# Angular 2 Reactive Form Isolate Scope

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am new to reactive forms. In below code, i have room type where I can add or remove form group. when I select any value of room type in drop-down it should populate the drop-down value in input box next to it. But I want to Isolate scope.

Basically If i add more than one group(Dropdown, textbox) and if i try to select any of the dropdown the value should reflect in textbox next to it and not all. I tried using ngModel but it populate values in all textbox bcoz of duplication of names in NgModel.

In my plunker. Red box is what i want but this for single dropdown I can achieve using ngModel. When we use FormArray we cannot use same name in ngModel.

Please help. I tried finding similar Questions but nothing helped me.

```html
<form [formGroup]="invoiceForm">
    <label>Package Title: </label>
    <input formControlName="Package_Title"/>
    <hr>
    <div formArrayName="HotelData">
      <div *ngFor="let hotel of invoiceForm.controls.HotelData.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i" >
        <fieldset>
          <label>Hotel Title </label>
          <input formControlName="Htitle" />
          <button (click)="addRoom(hotel.controls.RoomData)">Add Room</button>
          <div formArrayName="RoomData">
            <div *ngFor="let room of hotel.controls.RoomData.controls; let j = index" [formGroupName]="j">
              <fieldset>
                <label>Room Type</label>
                <select>
                  <option *ngFor="let a of list">{{a}}</option>
                </select>
                <input formControlName="Hotel_Room_Type">
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

[Plunker Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lehx81571Qy1QSKsa38c?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your updated plunkr code is kind of new requirement which does not fit for the question asked originally, so writing this second answer here...

**Simple change you need to do in your template code is:**

```
<fieldset>
    <label>Room Type</label>
    <select formControlName="color" #room_type>
         <option *ngFor="let a of list">{{a}}</option>
    </select>
    <input formControlName="Hotel_Room_Type" [(ngModel)]="room_type.value">
</fieldset>
```

This maintains the dynamism of form, so that you can add multiple Hotels, multiple rooms, and no information of one hotel and/or room conflicts with other.

I hope this is what you need. :)

Comment: No this wont works. It wont isolate the scope. I just updated Plunker with your code. I added 3-4 Room Type. If i change any of the dropdown it reflects everywhere

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just as query what is a standard term used to define this #id. element id, element reference. can you please share link to learn more on it. as i see it works in isolation.

Comment: Most welcome :) terminology for this is `Element Reference in Angular`, and you can read this article for better understanding https://myview.rahulnivi.net/local-references-angular-4-templates/

Comment: I'll delete my (non-English) comments, however, the link for working plunkr is  http://plnkr.co/edit/dZmdNnSoF5bTvW3Okoup?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your plunkr code,

you need to add this too..

**In your template:**

```
<select formControlName="Hotel_Room_Color">
    <option *ngFor="let a of list">{{a}}</option>
</select>
```

**In your Component:**

```
addRoom(hotel:any) {
    let group = this._formBuild.group({
      Hotel_Room_Type: [''],
      Hotel_Room_Color: ['']
    });
    hotel.push(group);
}
```

**Explanation:**

After these additions, all controls are available to your `formGroup`, and hence the form data is populated correctly.

Comment: I have updated my plunker. Red box is what i want but this for single dropdown I can achieve using ngModel. When we use FormArray we cannot use same name in ngModel. So is the way to solve this issue.

Comment: @Jay Your requirements are unclear. Can you give a proper scenario of what you are expecting. Any examples, or steps.???

Comment: Manoj Shukla I my plunker code, I need to achieve Red Box behavior in Blue Box.  In red Box when i select any value it automatically bind to text box next to it. I am able to do so using ngModel. In Blue Box I am doing FormArray, If I add more than one drop down and select value it changes value for all dropdown and input box as ngModel value is same. Basically I want to isolate dropdown value.